# How to have a single IP for Rapid Application Cluster (RAC) oracle cluster and WIndows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, oracle, ip-address, cluster-computing

I have a multi tier application that want to use a RAC to improve the availability of the server.

What we have now is, the client side sending a transaction data to the server side through a webservice. At client level, we need to specify the url address (IP address) as a path to send a data.

As for now, there are 2 oracle instance installed as a RAC at a server. 
1. 133.38.52.101
2. 133.38.52.102

Both of the server are connect to same Oracle Database (SAN storage).

Let say, the client side is pointing to .101. Suddenly the .101 machine is down, how can I possible to use the .102 without changing the point URL at the client side. Is there any configuration can be done at RAC or Windows Server 2008 for this type of problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) between client machine and application server machines.
2. Use Oracle's [transparent application failover](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/search?word=taf&partno=) functionality in OCI to achieve redundancy and load balancing between application server machines and RAC instances. DML transactions will be rolled back but selects will be transparently failed over.